# How to achieve setVideoScalingMode for early versions of Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

MediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode (int mode) is nice for API 16 and above allowing choosing between `VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT` and `VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING`.

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality for Android prior to API 16?

I have tried to set the dimensions of `SurfaceView` used by a MediaPlayer, but MediaPlayer crops the original video to fits whatever dimensions of the `SurfaceView`.

Answer (score 0):

Faced up with the same problem, get solution with this article
http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/surface-view-video-cropping
But with small change:
By default TextureView already has scale to make video fit screen aspect ratio, so you get left/right or top/bottom stripes for tall/wide videos. And when you use approach from article you are getting TextureView scale + scale calculated by updateTextureViewSize, so very large scale index. My solution for this problem is to calculate relative scale value:

```
float div = Math.max(scaleX,scaleY)-Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
matrix.setScale(1+div,1+div,pivotPointX,pivotPointY);
```

instead of

```
 matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
```